# How to write Unit test cases for Web hooks in c#?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, nunit, httprequest, webhooks

I have a web page which receives web hook request and i want to write Unit test cases (NUnit framework) for this web hook. I want to mock the web hook request (Post request) in unit test cases and pass the **request headers** and body as the **Json data** to the web page which receives request.

***Web page name***

```
/webhook/receiveWebHook.aspx
```

***Request Headers***

```
Content-Type: application/json
messageType: TestInsertNotification
```

***Request Body (Json data)***

```
{ 
   "Alias":"Test",
   "TransactionID":"123"
}
```

***Code in web page:***

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.ToUpper() == "POST")
      {
           object notification = null;
           string message = string.Empty;

           Int32 pID = InsertHTTPRequest(HttpContext.Current.Request); //Generate id in DB

           if (pID > 0 && this.Request.ContentType == "application/json")
           {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream, this.Request.ContentEncoding);
                message = sr.ReadToEnd();
                TextReader content = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)));
                JToken json = JToken.Load(new JsonTextReader(content));
                notification = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize(new JTokenReader(json), this.GetTypeOfMessage(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers("MessageType")));   
           }
            if (notification != null)
            {
                 if (notification is InsertNotification)
                 {
                      InsertNotification insertNotification = notification as InsertNotification;
                      DbInsertMethod(pID, message, insertNotification);
                 }
            }
      }
}
```

Can someone please help how to achieve unit testing for webhooks in c#? 
Also, please suggest how to pass HTTP Post request from Unit test method with Header and body (containing Json data)?

**P.S.:** Currently i'm using Postman to test the functionality of this webhook.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **RestSharp** library. For your case it looks like this:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class TestWebApp
{
    [Test]
    public void TestRequest()
    {
        IRestClient client = new RestClient($"{BaseUrl}/webhook/receiveWebHook.aspx");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("messageType", "TestInsertNotification");
        JObject jObjectbody = new JObject();
        jObjectbody.Add("Alias", "Test");
        jObjectbody.Add("TransactionID", "123");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", jObjectbody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```